# How to make a get request that does not reload the page but changes the URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, post, get

I am making a website where I can keep a track of clients.

When I select a client from the a list, it displays the data of the client.
Currently I use POST to send the client ID to the node js Server, which returns the data of the client:

```
async function getClientData(ID) 
{
    var data = {ID};
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    const response = await fetch('/getClientData', options)
    const responseData = await response.json();

    return responseData.clientData;
}
```

I want to make it so that when a client is selected it is reflected in the url with a `?clientID=000000` appended to the URL so that if I were to reload the page the same client would be selected and the information of the client is displayed. However, I do not want to reload the page when I am switching between clients.

I tried using GET. However, I cannot figure out how to use GET to get the client data for a particular client ID with the url changing.

To better understand what I am trying to do. If you do a google search and then search for something else. The url changes and search results change without the whole page reloading every time you do a different search and the previous searches can be accessed by going back on the browser.

I am relatively new to do this. So, any help would appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: use the api : history.pushState('','','clientid=xxx')

Comment: Oh thanks! That is exactly what I needed.